# Deserialize flat JSON to List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

Edit: I realized my issue of not using a `Dictionary<string, string>` right after posting this question, so I immediately deleted it. Looks like I accidentally undeleted it again. Sorry about everybody's time I wasted. I'll still leave it up in case someone else has the same brain fart as me.

I have a flat JSON like this:

```json
{
    "name1": "value1",
    "name2": "value2",
    "name3": "value3",
}
```

And I want to deserialize it to `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`, because I can't know what the names of the attributes are. Just doing

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(json)
```

does not work. It says

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair'2[System.String,System.String]]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

However, replacing the curly braces with square brackets is not valid JSON and throws an error as well.

Is there any way to do this without writing my own parser?

Comment: Isn't this just a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`? A `List<T>` would require `[]` braces around the object, not replacing them.

Comment: Flat JSON is straightforwardly deserialized to `IDictionary<string, string>`. You can do `.ToList()`  on this dictionary, if you need exactly `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`

Comment: It is not a list in the first place because you don't have an array, as the message says. Simply deserialize as a Dictionary.

Comment: I just didn't remember dictionaries are a thing when I wrote that question. early morning brain fart. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSON, `{}` denotes an object while `[]` denotes an array. What you have is an object, so it isn't immediately compatible with a list structure.

Instead, you can try converting it first to a dictionary, then to a list in a separate step.

```cs
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json)
    .ToList();
```

In the above code, `DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>` will convert the JSON into a `Dictionary<string, string>`. The LINQ method `ToList` is then used to convert the dictionary into a list, and by default this will produce a list of `KeyValuePair<string, string>`.

Comment: I just didn't remember dictionaries are a thing when I wrote that question. early morning brain fart. Thanks anyways